# Can someone explain this part of circuit from BQ500212A?

Tags: transistors, timer, charger, npn, pnp

As the title says, I am struggling to understand what this part of a circuit does. It's part of [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu928c/slvu928c.pdf?ts=1594940372649) evaluation module.

[image]

Is there any chance the BSS138 transistors will activate without the SNOOZE/SLEEP input? If so, how?

Comment: Delayed start with prioritized enable selection logic. Snooze and sleep are basically identical but sleep has a longer time constant and overrides sleep. It's all about charging C32 or C22 through different resistors.

Comment: It sounds like you worked with this kind of circuit before. Would it be possible to extend what you said above? Perhaps in an answer?

Comment: I haven't. All I did was look at it for a few minutes.

Comment: And seems like Q8 provides current to charge C32 quickly on power-on so there's no power-up delay.

Comment: @DKNguyen , I had an issue with the chip providing the SLEEP and SNOOZE signals. This threw my thinking off rails. You were right above. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are to provide a delayed start with sleep overriding the snooze.. Snooze and sleep are basically identical but sleep has a longer time constant and overrides sleep. It's all about charging C32 or C22 through different resistors.

D2 is there to let sleep override snooze.

Q8, C34, and R35 bypass sleep and snooze when power is first connected so there is no delay.